# Django can only handle ASGI/HTTP connections, not lifespan. in uvicorn

Tags: lifespan

**The problem:**

```
ValueError generic ASGI request Unhandled
Django can only handle ASGI/HTTP connections, not lifespan.
```

I'm using:

> Django==3.2.6
> gunicorn==20.1.0
> uvicorn==0.20.0

docker CMD: `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:9999 --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 erp.asgi:application -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker`

**The server works fine**
need to make sure if solution
`uvicorn --lifespan off` has any side-effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this warning:

1. add a custom worker with lifespan off

```
from uvicorn.workers import UvicornWorker


class MyUvicornWorker(UvicornWorker):
    CONFIG_KWARGS = {"lifespan": "off"}
```

2. user custom worker

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8888 --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 erp.asgi:application -k proj.uvicorn_worker.MyUvicornWorker
```

Tested on my Django 3.2.6, **Turning the Lifespan protocol implementation off** works

Untill Django 4.2.x django.core.asgi only [handle http](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.2.x/django/core/handlers/asgi.py)

```
# FIXME: Allow to override this.
        if scope["type"] != "http":
            raise ValueError(
                "Django can only handle ASGI/HTTP connections, not %s." % scope["type"]
            )
```

Answer (score 3):

To build on previous answer, I suggest following.

```
from uvicorn.workers import UvicornWorker


class DjangoUvicornWorker(UvicornWorker):
    """
    Generate UvicornWorker with lifespan='off', because Django does not
    (and probably will not https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31508)
    support Lifespan.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.config.lifespan = 'off'
```

That will leave any existing `CONFIG_KWARGS` in place, and only change the `lifespan` setting.

Then use that for the `--worker-class` setting (abbreviated as `-k`) on the command line for `gunicorn`. I put that class inside my `asgi.py` file -- because I don't use it in any other context -- but you can put it inside any module you want.